# two out of 3 if/elif python statements work

Tags: python, sql-server

Im having issues with importing as a tuple on 1 of my statements they should basically be identical as the other two but I get the following error on my second if/elif statement

```
importncdrfile
cursor.execute(importncdrdata,ncdr_tuple)
```

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 11 parameter markers, but 1808 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

the if/elif works for 2019q3 and 2020q1 but not for 2019q4 im not seeing why it shouldnt

```
importncdrdata = "INSERT INTO ncdr.dbo.ncdrdatatest (Hospital,YrQTRid,MetricKey,LineText,Year,Quarter,YrQtrRange,qtrnum,qtrden,qtrpercent,subgroup) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

importvolgroup = "INSERT INTO ncdr.dbo.ncdrvoldatatest (Hospital,YrQTRid,MetricKey,LineText,Year,Quarter,YrQtrRange,rqtrnum,rqtrden,rqtrpercent,volqtrnum,volqtrpercent,subgroup) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

class GUI():
def **init**(self):
# Create the root self.root
self.root = Tk()
# Set self.root title
self.root.title('NCDR Upload Tool')
# Set self.root size
self.root.geometry("700x305")
#Set self.root background color
self.root.config(background = "gray")
self.filename = ""

```
    def browseFiles(): 
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File",  filetypes = (("Excel File", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*"))) 
        # Change label contents 
        label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+self.filename)

    def importncdrfile():
        # Open the workbook and select the first worksheet
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(self.filename)
        sh = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
        # Function to import main set of data
        if yearqtrid.get() == "2019Q3":
            def excelToTuple(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, num, den, percent):
                for rownum in range(12, sh.nrows):
                    ncdr = tuple(['Hospital','YrQTRid','Metrickey','LineText','Year','Quarter','YrQtrRange','qtrnum','qtrden','qtrpercent','SubGroup'])
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        subgroup = row_values[metricKey]
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        continue
                    ncdr = (hospitalchosen.get(),yearqtrid.get(),row_values[metricKey],row_values[lineText],year,quarter,yrQtrRange,row_values[num],row_values[den],row_values[percent],subgroup)
                    ncdr_tuple.append(ncdr)

            # tuples to hold data
            ncdr_tuple = []
            # Imports data into MSSQL takes the above code and then runs the function against each set of data and then repeats for all 4 Quarters
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2018, 4, 20184, 2, 4, 6)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 1, 20191, 8, 10, 12)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 2, 20192, 14, 16, 18)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 3, 20193, 20, 22, 24)

            cursor.executemany(importncdrdata, ncdr_tuple)
            cursor.commit()

            # function to import volume group and rolling quarters
            def excelToTuplevol(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, rqtrnum, rqtrden, rqtrpercent, volnum, volpercent):
                for rownum in range(18, sh.nrows):
                    ncdrvol = tuple(['Hospital','YrQTRid','Metrickey','LineText','Year','Quarter','YrQtrRange','rqtrnum','rqtrden','rqtrpercent','volnum','volpercent','SubGroup'])
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        subgroup = row_values[metricKey]
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        continue
                    ncdrvol = (hospitalchosen.get(),yearqtrid.get(),row_values[metricKey],row_values[lineText],year,quarter,yrQtrRange,row_values[rqtrnum],row_values[rqtrden],row_values[rqtrpercent],row_values[volnum],row_values[volpercent],subgroup)
                    ncdr_voltuple.append(ncdrvol)

            ncdr_voltuple = []
            excelToTuplevol(n,0, 1, 2019, 3, 20193, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34)

            cursor.executemany(importvolgroup, ncdr_voltuple)
            cursor.commit()
            
        # 2019Q4 data import
        elif yearqtrid.get() == "2019Q4":
            def excelToTuple(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, num, den, percent):
                for rownum in range(18, sh.nrows):
                    ncdr = tuple(['Hospital','YrQTRid','Metrickey','LineText','Year','Quarter','YrQtrRange','qtrnum','qtrden','qtrpercent','SubGroup'])
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        subgroup = row_values[metricKey]
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        continue
                    ncdr = (hospitalchosen.get(),yearqtrid.get(),row_values[metricKey],row_values[lineText],year,quarter,yrQtrRange,row_values[num],row_values[den],row_values[percent],subgroup)
                    ncdr_tuple.append(ncdr)

            # Tuple to hold Data
            ncdr_tuple = []
            # Imports data into MSSQL takes the above code and then runs the function against each set of data and then repeats for all 4 Quarters
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 1, 20191, 2, 4, 6)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 2, 20192, 8, 10, 12)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 3, 20193, 14, 16, 18)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 4, 20194, 20, 22, 24)

            cursor.execute(importncdrdata,ncdr_tuple)
            cursor.commit()

            # function to import volume group and rolling quarters
            def excelToTuplevol(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, rqtrnum, rqtrden, rqtrpercent, volnum, volpercent):
                for rownum in range(18, sh.nrows):
                    ncdrvol = tuple(['Hospital','YrQTRid','Metrickey','LineText','Year','Quarter','YrQtrRange','rqtrnum','rqtrden','rqtrpercent','volnum','volpercent','SubGroup'])
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        subgroup = row_values[metricKey]
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        continue
                    ncdrvol = (hospitalchosen.get(),yearqtrid.get(),row_values[metricKey],row_values[lineText],year,quarter,yrQtrRange,row_values[rqtrnum],row_values[rqtrden],row_values[rqtrpercent],row_values[volnum],row_values[volpercent],subgroup)
                    ncdr_voltuple.append(ncdrvol)

            ncdr_voltuple = []
            excelToTuplevol(n,0, 1, 2019, 4, 20194, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34)

            cursor.executemany(importvolgroup, ncdr_voltuple)
            cursor.commit()

        elif yearqtrid.get() == "2020Q1":
            def excelToTuple(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, num, den, percent):
                for rownum in range(18, sh.nrows):
                    ncdr = tuple(['Hospital','YrQTRid','Metrickey','LineText','Year','Quarter','YrQtrRange','qtrnum','qtrden','qtrpercent','SubGroup'])
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        subgroup = row_values[metricKey]
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        continue
                    ncdr = (hospitalchosen.get(),yearqtrid.get(),row_values[metricKey],row_values[lineText],year,quarter,yrQtrRange,row_values[num],row_values[den],row_values[percent],subgroup)
                    ncdr_tuple.append(ncdr)

            # Tuple to hold Data
            ncdr_tuple = []
            # Imports data into MSSQL takes the above code and then runs the function against each set of data and then repeats for all 4 Quarters
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 2, 20192, 2, 4, 6)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 3, 20193, 8, 10, 12)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2019, 4, 20194, 14, 16, 18)
            excelToTuple(n,0, 1, 2020, 1, 20201, 20, 22, 24)

            cursor.executemany(importncdrdata,ncdr_tuple)
            cursor.commit()

            # function to import volume group and rolling quarters
            def excelToTuplevol(hospital, metricKey, lineText, year, quarter, yrQtrRange, rqtrnum, rqtrden, rqtrpercent, volnum, volpercent):
                for rownum in range(18, sh.nrows):
                    ncdrvol = tuple(['Hospital','YrQTRid','Metrickey','LineText','Year','Quarter','YrQtrRange','rqtrnum','rqtrden','rqtrpercent','volnum','volpercent','SubGroup'])
                    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        subgroup = row_values[metricKey]
                    if isinstance(row_values[metricKey], str) :
                        continue
                    ncdrvol = (hospitalchosen.get(),yearqtrid.get(),row_values[metricKey],row_values[lineText],year,quarter,yrQtrRange,row_values[rqtrnum],row_values[rqtrden],row_values[rqtrpercent],row_values[volnum],row_values[volpercent],subgroup)
                    ncdr_voltuple.append(ncdrvol)

            ncdr_voltuple = []
            excelToTuplevol(n,0, 1, 2020, 1, 20201, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34)

            cursor.executemany(importvolgroup, ncdr_voltuple)
            cursor.commit()

        label_uploaded.configure(text = "File Uploaded")
```

Comment: You're calling `cursor.executemany(...)` in the two conditions that "work" but you're calling `cursor.execute(...)` in the one that raises the error. What do you think you should change?

Comment: it needs to be executemany